# Missing value for primary key id on Entity

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, doctrine

i'm trying return my entity but i get this error when I make a request and i don't know what i'm doing wrong with this relations
(1/2) OutOfBoundsException
Missing value for primary key id on \ApiBundle\Entity\Type

My Session entity:

```
<?php

namespace Primepass\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="session", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="session_id_uindex", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Primepass\ApiBundle\Repository\SessionRepository")
 */
class Session
{

    /**
     * @var UuidInterface
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Theater
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Theater")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="theater_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $theater;

    /**
     * @var Movie
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Movie")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $movie;

    /**
     * @var Type
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="audio_type", referencedColumnName="type_name")
     * })
     */
    private $audioType;

    /**
     * @var Type
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="screen_type", referencedColumnName="type_name")
     * })
     */
    private $screenType;

    /**
     * @var Type
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="room_type", referencedColumnName="type_name")
     * })
     */
    private $roomType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="room_name",type="string")
     */
    private $roomName;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var \Time
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hour", type="time", nullable=false)
     */
    private $hour;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="2001-01-01 00:00:00"})
     */
    private $createdAt = '2001-01-01 00:00:00';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="2001-01-01 00:00:00"})
     */
    private $updatedAt = '2001-01-01 00:00:00';

    public function getId(): UuidInterface
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTheater(): ?Theater
    {
        return $this->theater;
    }

    public function setTheater(?Theater $theater): self
    {
        $this->theater = $theater;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMovie(): ?Movie
    {
        return $this->movie;
    }

    public function setMovie(?Movie $movie): self
    {
        $this->movie = $movie;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAudioType(): ?Type
    {
        return $this->audioType;
    }

    public function setAudioType(?Type $audioType): self
    {
        $this->audioType = $audioType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getScreenType(): ?Type
    {
        return $this->screenType;
    }

    public function setScreenType(?Type $screenType): self
    {
        $this->screenType = $screenType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoomType(): ?Type
    {
        return $this->roomType;
    }

    public function setRoomType(?Type $roomType): self
    {
        $this->roomType = $roomType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoomName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->roomName;
    }

    public function setRoomName($roomName): self
    {
        $this->roomName = $roomName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(?int $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHour(): ?\Time
    {
        return $this->hour;
    }

    public function setHour(\Time $hour): self
    {
        $this->hour = $hour;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive(bool $isActive): self
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Type Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Primepass\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Type
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Primepass\ApiBundle\Repository\TypeRepository")
 */
class Type
{
    /**
     * @var UuidInterface
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type_name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $typeName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type_info", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $typeInfo;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="2001-01-01 00:00:00"})
     */
    private $createdAt = '2001-01-01 00:00:00';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="2001-01-01 00:00:00"})
     */
    private $updatedAt = '2001-01-01 00:00:00';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TicketRules", mappedBy="types")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ticket_rules_type")
     */
    private $ticketRuleScreens;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ticketRuleScreens = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): UuidInterface
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTypeName(): string
    {
        return $this->typeName;
    }

    public function setTypeName(string $typeName): self
    {
        $this->typeName = $typeName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTypeInfo(): string
    {
        return $this->typeInfo;
    }

    public function setTypeInfo(string $typeInfo): self
    {
        $this->typeInfo = $typeInfo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTicketRuleScreens()
    {
        return $this->ticketRuleScreens;
    }

    public function setTicketRuleScreens($ticketRuleScreens): self
    {
        $this->ticketRuleScreens = $ticketRuleScreens;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I expected a json return with a paginator but has something wrong with Session model

Comment: the error appears, if you try to persist (and flush) an entity, which has no id. since you've chosen the `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")`, I assume your generator doesn't work as expected?

Comment: What is the stack trace? The error seems to indicate that something tries to get the id of your entity, but it doesn't have an id. Since the id is auto-generated upon flush, maybe you try to output an incomplete entity somewhere?

Comment: To completely avoid the problem, you might consider to require the uuid in the constructor, and generate it before you create the entity. That way the entity always has an id and you don't need to save it before using it.